# Variable name in function call in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to achieve the following pseudo code:

```
function processAboutLink(){

}

function processServicesLink(){

}

var variableName = 'about';

process + variableName + Link();

var variableName = 'services';

process + variableName + Link();
```

I'm aware that the code above isn't real but is a logical representation. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It would be more convenient to have an object, because you can access properties dynamically:

```
var processLinkFunctions = {
  about:    function() { ... },
  services: function() { ... }
};
```

Then, it's as easy as:

```
processLinkFunctions[variableName]();
```

This is basically the same as `processLinkFunctions.about()` if `variableName === "about"`.

Answer (score 4):

You might want to use object literals for namespacing instead

```
var process = {
    services: function(){...},
    about: function(){...}
}
```

then calling them:

```
process[variable]();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you make the functions properties of an object, you can then call them by name (and without resorting to `eval` !):

```
var functions = {
    about: function() { ... },
    services: function() { ... }
};

var name = 'about';
functions[name]();
```

Comment: Care to explain why resorting to eval is bad?

Comment: @amaters because it leads to insecure code, and potentially undefined behaviour.  In ES5 strict mode it's completely disallowed.

Answer (score -1):

EDIT don;t use eval. It seems to be dangerous and leads to undefined behaviour.

wrong answer:

```
eval('process' + variableName + 'Link()');
```

should work

Comment: Thanks for the pointer T.J.
Seems someone downvotes without telling why using eval is bad. Never knew using eval is bad practice.

Comment: @amaters sorry, I just couldn't help myself!  It's an automatic reaction any time I see `eval` in an answer...

Comment: @amaters yeah, yeah, I know, but it gets tiresome having to explain it _every_ time!  I think this was the third answer just today.

Comment: answer edited. I learned something as well. Thanks for explaining it over and over. After all we are here to learn.