# Variable in javascript function - the simple answer

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10350352/variable-name-in-function-call-in-javascript) to be exactly the same problem I'm facing, but the answers suggested using objects for dynamic access. This might be well and good, but I'm looking for the exact simple answer on how to include a variable in a function's name.

I'm using [ClockPick](http://www.jnathanson.com/index.cfm?page=jquery/clockpick/ClockPick)  and dare not mess up the code, so I can't use objects or anything else. The problem is that with `[ $("#clockpick"+x).clockpick ]` the result isn't `[ $("#clockpick0").clockpick ]` but instead `[ $("#clockpick"+x).clockpick ]`.

This all happens inside a PHP loop and it looks something like this:

```
var x = 0; (declared previously outside of the loop)
<script>
function doit()
{
  $("#clockpick"+x).clockpick
  ({
      starthour: 7,
      endhour: 20
      ...
  });
}
x++;
```

timepicker.php

```
<script>var times = 0;</script>
<?php
$goo = $_POST['goo'];
for ($foo = 0; $foo < $goo; $foo++)
{
  ?>
  <script>
  function clocker()
  {
  $("#clockpick"+times).clockpick
  ({
    starthour: 7,
    endhour: 20
  });
  } times++;
  </script>
  <?php
  print "<input type='text' id='clockpick$foo' onclick='clocker()' />
?>
```

As mentioned, this works ok if I manually set "times" to a number, but as you can see, I don't know what number $goo has. In all, this is still a simplified demo from the actual page of 153 rows.

Comment: Can't see PHP or any other loop here.

Comment: Seems fine. How do you know the result is wrong?

Comment: And this has nothing to do with the linked question, here your jquery selector is variable (which should always work), not your function name.

Comment: Is `x` a PHP variable or a Javascript variable? Can you show us your PHP as well?

Comment: Artyom - I didn't include the whole page in the example. Basically php loops an input field that's tied to this js so that when a user clicks on the field, it should trigger this script. It works all right if I manually test it like this [ $("#clockpick5").clockpick ]. It then works on the fifth textfield, but since I don't know how many fields are going to be generated, I thought of using js variable mentioned previously. So I know the code works just fine, but the problem is that I can't figure out how to get that "x" variable to the function name.

Comment: Pawel - the page this is in doesn't trigger the js script when clicking on the textfield (see previous answer). And when I look at the source code via the browser, it doesn't show $("#clockpick*number*").clockpick, but instead $("#clockpick"+x).clockpick

Comment: Duh, sorry for the wrong title. At first I didn't have function clocker() at all. Though the problem still persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a javascript variable to be incremented in a php loop.
The problem is that php will just write your javascript code as is, printing `$("#clockpick"+times)` at each iteration of the php loop.
To achieve what you want to do, you should use `$foo` instead of the useless javascript variable `times` like this

```
<?php
$goo = $_POST['goo'];
for ($foo = 0; $foo < $goo; $foo++)
{
?>
<script>
function clocker()
{
<?php
print "$('#clockpick$foo').clockpick"
?>
({
    starthour: 7,
    endhour: 20
});
}
</script>
<?php
print "<input type='text' id='clockpick$foo' onclick='clocker()' />"
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you, now it works just like a dream. Though it still doesn't call the script, but I guess that's another problem altogether.